# Why does most recently drawn arc have a fill of black even though fill is set to 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to add a circle with a 40px border(stroke) and with no background(fill)

And i have gotten it working - it is just the most recently drawn circle has its fill as black even though I am setting it (and all the others) to 'rbg(0,0,0,0)'

```
  public animate(milliseconds: any) {
    const elapsed = milliseconds - this.Configs.lastStep;
    this.Configs.lastStep = milliseconds;
    if (this.canvas) {
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
    this.update(elapsed);
    this.ctx.fill();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }

  public draw(milliseconds: number) {
    const colors = ["#270f36", "#632b6c", "#c76b98", "#f09f9c", "#fcc3a3"];

    this.ctx.save();
    for (let ring of this.rings) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)";
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = randomItemFromArray(colors);
      this.ctx.arc(ring.getOrigin.x, ring.getOrigin.y, ring.getRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      this.ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      this.ctx.fill();
      this.ctx.stroke();
    }
   this.ctx.restore();
  }
  public update(elapsed: number) {
        this.draw(elapsed);
}
```

I want all of the rings to be transparent - but the last one added to the rings array is always fill black.

I am stumped - any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is an example of what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLXSx.png)

Comment: Wouldn't `this.ctx.restore` reset the fill color each time after drawing? Presumably the default fill color is black. Also where in this code are you setting the last fill color to transparent black? Also, if you try to fill with transparent black and the circle has already been filled before, then it won't look any different.

Comment: Why are you even calling `.fill()` if you don't want a fill?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `ctx.fill()` in your `animate` function. At this time, you did `restore()` your context's properties to what they were when you called `ctx.save()`, and `fillStyle` got restored to `'black'`.
However, the current activePath that all pen operations made after the last `ctx.beginPath()` is still active. That's why it fills only the last arc.

Now if you only want the strokes, simply remove **all** the calls to `fill()` and any reference to `fillStyle` now become irrelevant.

And as a final note, `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` are doing only harm here.
Also, since `lineWidth` doesn't change, you can set it once only before you start the animation.
So all you need in your `draw` method is

```
draw(milliseconds) {
  const colors = ["#270f36", "#632b6c", "#c76b98", "#f09f9c", "#fcc3a3"];

  for (let ring of this.rings) {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = randomItemFromArray(colors);
    this.ctx.arc(ring.getOrigin.x, ring.getOrigin.y, ring.getRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```js
class Ring {
  constructor() {
    this.getOrigin = {
      x: (Math.random() * innerWidth / 4) + (innerWidth / 2),
      y: (Math.random() * innerHeight / 4) + (innerHeight / 2)
    };
    this.getRadius = (Math.random() * Math.min(innerHeight, innerWidth) / 4) + 50;
  }
}
class Drawer {
  constructor() {
    this.rings = Array.from({length: 8}, ()=>new Ring());
    this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = innerHeight;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 10;    
  }
animate(milliseconds) {
//    const elapsed = milliseconds - this.Configs.lastStep;
//    this.Configs.lastStep = milliseconds;
    if (this.canvas) {
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
    this.update(0);    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
  }
  draw(milliseconds) {
    const colors = ["#270f36", "#632b6c", "#c76b98", "#f09f9c", "#fcc3a3"];

    for (let ring of this.rings) {
      this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.strokeStyle = randomItemFromArray(colors);
      this.ctx.arc(ring.getOrigin.x, ring.getOrigin.y, ring.getRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
      this.ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
  update(elapsed) {
    this.draw(elapsed);
  }
}
const drawer = new Drawer();
drawer.animate();


function randomItemFromArray(arr) {
  return arr[(arr.length * Math.random()) | 0];
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```